# Broadcasting over two arrays with different shapes (Numpy-Python)

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
first_array = array([[1, 8, 3, 9, 2],
                     [2, 6, 4, 1, 9],
                     [4, 2, 12, 8, 16],
                     [5, 3, 7, 18, 21],
                     [6, 20, 4, 8, 24]])
```

So an array with shape `(5, 5)`

Now I have a second array, which is a slice of the first:

```
second_array = array([[1, 8, 3, 9, 2],
                     [2, 6, 4, 1, 9]])
```

An array with shape `(2, 5)`.

Now I want to subtract every vector of the first array by the vectors of the second array subsequently(excluding- in the first array- the vector of the second array I'm using to subtract), element-wise. I want to this for every vector of the second array.

So I want to have as an output:

```
subtracted_array = array([[[1, -2, 1, -8, 7],
                           [3, -6, 9, -1, 14],
                           [4, -5, 4, 9, 19],
                           [5, 12, 1, -1, 22]],
                          [[-1, 2, -1, 8, -7],
                           [2, -4, 8, 7, 7],
                           [3, -3, 3, 17, 12],
                           [4, 14, 0, 7, 15]]])
```

So this is an array with shape `(2, 4, 5)`

How do we do this with broadcasting?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you more.

Comment: your example reflects exactly what I want.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. What are you subtracting off when you reach the end of the second array?

Comment: Please show an example with arrays shaped (6, 3) and (3, 3) or something like that, and generate the expected output by hand

Comment: I will edit it. But give me some time to do it, instead of closing to vote immediately.

Comment: The close vote reflects the current state of the question. You were provided [ask] instructions while you were asking it. Once you fix the question to make sense, I will be more than happy to reverse my votes.

Comment: Specifically, the type of slice you have is important.

Comment: @MadPhysicist fair enough. I hope the example is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this code do what you meant you needed done?
You are welcomed to test it on your test case and update me if you need more help.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5)
arr_slice = arr[:2, :]

# "outer" tensor subtraction
arr_sub = arr_slice[:, None, :] - arr[None, :, :]
# create an index map of the vector combinations
idx0, idx1 = np.mgrid[:2, :10]
idx0, idx1 = idx0.flatten(), idx1.flatten()
# find the irrelevent combinations and remove them
remove_same = (1 - (idx0 == idx1)).astype(bool)
idx0, idx1 = idx0[remove_same], idx1[remove_same]

arr_sub = arr_sub[idx0, idx1, :].reshape(2, 9, 5)
```

**EDIT:** here's a more efficient method:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5)
arr_slice = arr[:2, :]

# create an index map of the vector combinations
idx0, idx1 = np.mgrid[:2, :10]
idx0, idx1 = idx0.flatten(), idx1.flatten()
# find the irrelevent combinations and remove them
remove_same = (1 - (idx0 == idx1)).astype(bool)
idx0, idx1 = idx0[remove_same], idx1[remove_same]

arr_sub = arr_slice[idx0, :] - arr[idx1, :]

arr_sub = arr_sub.reshape(2, 9, 5)
```

output:

```
arr = 
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49]]

arr_slice = 
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]

arr_sub = 
[[[ -5  -5  -5  -5  -5]
  [-10 -10 -10 -10 -10]
  [-15 -15 -15 -15 -15]
  [-20 -20 -20 -20 -20]
  [-25 -25 -25 -25 -25]
  [-30 -30 -30 -30 -30]
  [-35 -35 -35 -35 -35]
  [-40 -40 -40 -40 -40]
  [-45 -45 -45 -45 -45]]

 [[  5   5   5   5   5]
  [ -5  -5  -5  -5  -5]
  [-10 -10 -10 -10 -10]
  [-15 -15 -15 -15 -15]
  [-20 -20 -20 -20 -20]
  [-25 -25 -25 -25 -25]
  [-30 -30 -30 -30 -30]
  [-35 -35 -35 -35 -35]
  [-40 -40 -40 -40 -40]]]
```

**EDIT 2:** I subtracted the arrays in the wrong order (the whole array from the slice instead of the other way around). So here's a fix and this time I'm using your example:

```
import numpy as np

first_array = np.array(
    [[1, 8, 3, 9, 2],
     [2, 6, 4, 1, 9],
     [4, 2, 12, 8, 16],
     [5, 3, 7, 18, 21],
     [6, 20, 4, 8, 24]]
)

arr_slice = slice(None, 2)
second_array = first_array[arr_slice]

expected_subtracted_array = np.array(
    [[[[1, -2, 1, -8, 7],
       [3, -6, 9, -1, 14],
       [4, -5, 4, 9, 19],
       [5, 12, 1, -1, 22]],
      [[-1, 2, -1, 8, -7],
       [2, -4, 8, 7, 7],
       [3, -3, 3, 17, 12],
       [4, 14, 0, 7, 15]]]]
)

# create an index map of the vector combinations
idx0, idx1 = np.mgrid[:second_array.shape[0], :first_array.shape[0]]
idx0, idx1 = idx0.flatten(), idx1.flatten()
# find the irrelevent combinations and remove them
remove_same = (1 - (idx0 == idx1)).astype(bool)
idx0, idx1 = idx0[remove_same], idx1[remove_same]
arr_sub = first_array[idx1, :] - second_array[idx0, :]
arr_sub = arr_sub.reshape(second_array.shape[0], first_array.shape[0]-1, first_array.shape[1])

(arr_sub == expected_subtracted_array).all()
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Computing a bunch of zeros is wasteful. Will post answer momentarily.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you're right. I added a slightly more efficient method

Comment: yes, I wrongly phrased the question in the beginning. Adjusted your code to what you have edited right now and it works indeed. Brilliant. Upvoted and accepted your answer.